# How to use OAuth1 with aiohttp

Tags: python, http, asynchronous, oauth, aiohttp

I have successfully implemented OAuth1 with the regular `requests` module like this:

```
import requests
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1


oauth = OAuth1(client_key=oauth_cred["consumer_key"], client_secret=oauth_cred["consumer_secret"], resource_owner_key=oauth_cred["access_token"], resource_owner_secret=oauth_cred["access_token_secret"])

session = requests.Session()

session.auth = oauth
```

When trying to transfer this to `aiohttp`, I have not been able to get it to work. Substituting `aiohttp.ClientSession()` for `requests.Session()` gives me `{'errors': [{'code': 215, 'message': 'Bad Authentication data.'}]}`.

I have looked at some solutions on the internet like https://github.com/klen/aioauth-client, but this seems to be a different approach. I just want it to function exactly like in my example above.

I tried

```
import aiohttp
from aioauth_client import TwitterClient


oauth = TwitterClient(consumer_key=oauth_cred["consumer_key"], consumer_secret=oauth_cred["consumer_secret"], oauth_token=oauth_cred["access_token"], oauth_token_secret=oauth_cred["access_token_secret"])

session = aiohttp.ClientSession()

session.auth = oauth
```

but I got the same error.

How can I get this to work?

Comment: If you are looking for async OAuth 1.0 clients, you may try the HTTPX version Authlib: https://docs.authlib.org/en/latest/client/httpx.html#httpx-oauth-1-0

Comment: were you able to solve this? I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Using [oauthlib](https://github.com/oauthlib/oauthlib):

```py
import oauthlib.oauth1, aiohttp, asyncio

async def main():
    # Create the Client. This can be reused for multiple requests.
    client = oauthlib.oauth1.Client(
        client_key = oauth_cred['consumer_key'],
        client_secret = oauth_cred['consumer_secret'],
        resource_owner_key = oauth_cred['access_token'],
        resource_owner_secret = oauth_cred['access_token_secret']
    )

    # Define your request. In my code I'm POSTing so that's what I have here,
    # but if you're doing something different you'll need to change this a bit.
    uri = '...'
    http_method = 'POST'
    body = '...'
    headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }

    # Sign the request data. This needs to be called for each request you make.
    uri,headers,body = client.sign(
        uri = uri,
        http_method = http_method,
        body = body,
        headers = headers
    )

    # Make your request with the signed data.
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.post(uri, data=body, headers=headers, raise_for_status=True) as r:
            ...

# asyncio.run has a bug on Windows in Python 3.8 https://bugs.python.org/issue39232
#asyncio.run(main())
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
```

The `oauthlib.oauth1.Client` constructor takes a bunch more parameters too if you need them (for basic use you don't). The [official documentation](https://oauthlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/oauth1/client.html) isn't very thorough, but the [doc comment on the method itself](https://github.com/oauthlib/oauthlib/blob/5cf4c3d7fb59338050392147546155d5e9ee197e/oauthlib/oauth1/rfc5849/__init__.py#L101-L121) is pretty good.

The [doc comment on the `Client.sign` method](https://github.com/oauthlib/oauthlib/blob/5cf4c3d7fb59338050392147546155d5e9ee197e/oauthlib/oauth1/rfc5849/__init__.py#L264-L291) has more information about the parameters it takes.